# How do i query a collection in Cosmos DB in two steps?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a single collection in Cosmos DB where documents are separated in two types. Let's call them `board` and `pin`.

**Board:**

```
{
  "id": "board-1",
  "description": "A collection of nice pins",
  "author": "user-a",
  "moments": [
    {
      "id": "pin-1"
    },
    {
      "id": "pin-2"
    },
    {
      "id": "pin-3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Pin:**

```
{
  "id": "pin-1",
  "description": "Number 1 is the best pin",
  "author": "user-b"
}
```

I know how to query just a board of pin based on id. But i Need to query that (based on the id of the board) which gives me all the pins contained in a board. It would also be good if I could filter out one or more parts of the Pins.

Example: Not returning the author to the client.

```
{
  "id": "pin-1",
  "description": "Number 1 is the best pin"
},
{
  "id": "pin-2",
  "description": "Number 2 is very funny"
}..etc
```

I know I could handle this logic in the client app by making two requests, but is it possible to write a query for Cosmos DB that handles this?

Comment: Next time please whatch your formatation.

Comment: Thank you Hille! I'm not used to the stackoverflow editor. I ment to post like your improved recommendation but I must have done it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No, currently you can not  join different documents in single sql query.**

DocumentDB is schemaless and there is no hard concept of "references" like in a relational DB world. The referencing ids you have in your documents are just regular string data to DocumentDB and their special meaning (of linking to other documents) exists only in your application. Querying is currently just finding documents or parts of a document by some given predicates. It is carried out on documents independently of each other.

As a sidenote: I imagine it is by design as such chosen restriction enable potential of parallelism and probably contribute to the low-latency dream they are intended to deliver.

This does not mean that what you need is impossible. Options to consider:

**Option 1: reference redesign**

If you had a data design where the `board`-`bin` relationship data would have been stored on the `pin`-side, then you could have queried all pins in `board-1` with single query, along the lines of:

```
select * from pin where pin.boardId = @boardId
```

It's quite common that you would need to denormalize your data model to some extent to optimize RU usage. Sometimes it is beneficial to duplicate some parent information to referencing documents. Or even store the relationship on both ends if the data is not too volatile and being read a lot from both sides. As a downside, keeping data is sync on writes becomes a bit more complicated. Mmmm, tradeoffs...

If redesign is an option then see the talk [Modeling Data for NoSQL Document Databases from //build/2016 by Ryan CrawCour and David Makogon](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P468). It should give you some ideas to consider.

When designing data for documentdB then keep in mind that in DocumentDB storage is relatively cheap, processing power (RU) is what you pay for.

**Option 2: stored procedures**

If you want/need to optimize storage/latency and cannot modify the data design and really-really need to perform such query in single roundtrip then you could build a stored procedure to do the queries on server-side and then pack the results into single returned Json message within DocumentDB.

See [Azure Cosmos DB server-side programming: Stored procedures, database triggers, and UDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming) for more detail about what can be done and how.

I imagine you may get slightly better latency (due to single call) and slightly worse overall RU usage (extra work for SP execution, transaction, merging the results), but definitely test your case before commiting.

I consider this option a bit dirty as:
1. combining documents by higher level needs is logic and hence should not be implemented in database, but with your application logic layer.
1. JS in DocumentDB is more cumbersome to develop, debug and maintain.

**Option 3: change nothing**

.. and just do the 2 calls. It's simple and may just as likely end up the best  solution in the long run (considering overall cost of design, development, maintenance, changes, etc..).